# How to print LOCAL byte with WinApi's WriteConsole

Tags: pointers, memory, stack, masm, masm32

It's hard for me to clarify my question, but I'll try. I'm trying to learn MASM32 and I have a task to print some text in console without using .data or .const. The problem is that LOCAL puts variable on stack, but not in static memory. So i cant get their address (offset), and WriteConsole uses a pointer to text's address in memory. Any thoughts on how to deal with this problem? Thanks!
I have this:

```
.data
string db 10 'somestring'

.code
WriteToConsole PROC 
    LOCAL handle :DWORD
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11
    mov handle, eax
    mov edx, offset string
    invoke WriteConsoleA, handle, edx, 10, 0, 0
    xor eax, eax
    ret
WriteToConsole ENDP
```

And I want something like that:

````
.code
WriteToConsole PROC 
    LOCAL string[10] :SBYTE
    LOCAL handle :DWORD
    invoke GetStdHandle, -11
    mov handle, eax
    mov edx, offset string ;impossible because of stack
    invoke WriteConsoleA, handle, edx, 10, 0, 0 ;can't call without a pointer
    xor eax, eax
    ret
WriteToConsole ENDP```
````

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer:

```
 LOCAL string[10] :DWORD
 lea edx, string
 invoke WriteConsoleA, handle, edx, stringlength, 0, 0
```

Loading effective address instead of an offset helps!